# ConverseJS and OpenFire

Tags: apache, xmpp, openfire, ejabberd, converse.js

I'm trying to connect converesejs example to an openfire server which is istalled on my localhost, but the connection can not be estableshed (I don't know why). However I can connect to openfire server with Psi. I think that the problem is with http-bind...

In conversejs example there is such code that should be editied by me.

```
<script>
require(['converse'], function (converse) {
    converse.initialize({
        allow_otr: true,
        auto_list_rooms: false,
        auto_subscribe: false,
        bosh_service_url: 'http://localhost:7070/http-bind', // my connection manager of an openfire 
        debug: true ,
        hide_muc_server: false,
        i18n: locales['en'], // Refer to ./locale/locales.js to see which locales are supported
        prebind: false,
        show_controlbox_by_default: true,
        xhr_user_search: false,
    });
});</script>
```

I found some information that Apache config (httpd.conf) must be edited. So I uncommented proxy_module and proxy_http_module.

And I set up such params in httpd.conf:

```
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPass /http-bind http://127.0.0.1:7070/http-bind/
ProxyPassReverse /http-bind http://127.0.0.1:7070/http-bind/
```

But this did't help. When I'm trying to login to the server using conversejs example page it stays in status "Connecting"...

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I am trying to get converseJS work on an application working myself with openfire on the server. How is it treating you? Should I go ahead with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to configure OpenFire to support BOSH (Bidirectional-streams Over Synchronous HTTP).

Log in to the admin console, then go to Server-> Server Settings -> HTTP Binding.

Comment: Thank you for an answer. I checked everything once more. The problem was that I used: bosh_service_url: 'http://localhost:7070/http-bind', instead of bosh_service_url: 'http://localhost/http-bind',